# Is it possible to refine a Google Search(with Google API) to use in an application

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm new to Google API's, and I've been trying to code an web app (that later I want to turn into a mobile app). For it to work it would be very helpful to use Google Search Engine and then refine the search with my own code. I wanted to know if it is possible to do that, and how to do it.
For example, lets say that I want to create an app that the user inputs a search request(like "where can I buy a book"), then this search is redirected to use Google Search(google will search for me "where can I buy a book"), and it will give me A LOT of results. After that, in the back end of my app I refine this search to give me only certain results(amazon, ebay, bookstorenum3, someotherBookStore).

So basically I want google to do a search for me and then I want to control and refine that search in my App and give it back to the user. Is it possible to do that??
Thank you!!